# Dot "cpbitmap" Images (imgaename.cpbitmap)

Tags: image, file, image-processing

How can I convert the .cpbitmap images to .png or common images type ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Here's some code from CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Apple_CPBitmap_Reader.aspx

Comment: @MarkRansom I saw that before I asked here... that isn't for Mac OS X, that is for windows, and I don't have Windows, I have a Mac...

Comment: That link doesn't just provide code, it provides a description of the file which is trivially simple. Just code it up in whatever language you have available. Or if you have a utility that can convert fixed-size images with no compression and no header, use that.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks, I will try that; I thought that I may find a app for converting .cpbitmap to .png...

Comment: Glad my article helped in some way! :)

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and the python-imaging package (version 3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1) and the Image.fromstring() has been renamed to frombytes(). I can confirm the solution from Mark and Alex works properly with this update. I've posted a Gist here for convenience: https://gist.github.com/danielsharvey/929a525712a2b89ebb561226cc32f3e7

Comment: The only thin that worked for me was this code: https://github.com/sh00tg0a1/cpbitmap_convertor/tree/master/python (run the .py script no the py2 and use the requirements file). If you are on a mac and need to simply set up a virtual environment use my script cvenv here https://github.com/LudvigWesterdahl/Scripts/blob/master/cvenv (usage: cvenv -r requirements.txt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick Python program to do it. I wasn't able to test it because I don't have any .cpbitmap images to use.

```
from PIL import Image
import struct
with open(filename) as f:
    contents = f.read()
unk1, width, height, unk2, unk3, unk4 = struct.unpack('<6i', contents[-24:])
im = Image.fromstring('RGBA', (width,height), contents, 'raw', 'RGBA', 0, 1)
im.save('converted.png')
```

Comment: I have put the code above into a file and named it "convert_cpbitmap.py" and launched it and i got this error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../Desktop/untitled folder/convert_cpbitmap.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ImportError: No module named PIL"

Comment: @user1028111, PIL is an optional component that you have to download and install. http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

Comment: I have been trying to install it on mac os x lion all day with no luck :\

Comment: I have converted it, but the colors are wrong, how to fix that ?

Comment: @user1028111, if you can post your original image somewhere I can diagnose it. Otherwise try changing one of the 'RGBA' to 'BGRA'.

Comment: great, it worked, thank you very much :D just two more question is there a way to make this a GUI program (for easier use) ? also, how do I pass filename with terminal because I didn't know how to so I changed it to the image path in the code...

Comment: and, if I want to convert it to another type (other than png) do I need to just change the `im.save('converted.png')` to `im.save('converted.gif')` or `im.save('converted.jpg')` ?

Comment: @user1028111, yes just change the extension and PIL will figure out the correct format, or you can add a parameter to `save` to specify it directly. P.S. if my answer solved your problem, clicking on the uparrow and checkmark to the left of the answer would be appreciated!

Comment: Just one more python question that I couldn't find an answer that worked... when I ran the program I wrote this in the terminal `python /path/to/file/convert.py` and I replaced `filename` in `convert.py` to the location of my image, so, my question is can I keep the variable `filename` and set or pass its value via terminal ?

Comment: Causes Python to crash for me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the idea to write python code is excellent for it is easier to execute than to run some xcode stuff.

As the previous author stated, he did not tested the code, but I did. What I found is that it produces the image in which RED and BLUE components are misplaces.

That is why I decided to post a correct version of this code here:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from PIL import Image,ImageOps
import struct
import sys
if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print "Need two args: filename and result_filename\n";
    sys.exit(0)
filename = sys.argv[1]
result_filename = sys.argv[2]

with open(filename) as f:
    contents = f.read()
    unk1, width, height, unk2, unk3, unk4 = struct.unpack('<6i', contents[-24:])
    im = Image.fromstring('RGBA', (width,height), contents, 'raw', 'RGBA', 0, 1)
    r,g,b,a = im.split()
    im = Image.merge('RGBA', (b,g,r,a))
    im.save(result_filename)
```

Put this code in the file decode_cpbitmap, do

`chmod 755 decode_cpbitmap`

to make it executable and now you may call it as follows:

`./decode_cpbitmap input_filename output_filename`

where input_filename is a file '*.cpbitmap' that you already have and want to decode, and output_filename is smth.png (it will be created by this code).

---

You may get an error

`ImportError: No module named PIL`

Then you need to install PIL python module. I will not explain how to install python modules for you may find it elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to convert images from iOS 11, and these scripts do not work. Today the size of each row is rounded up to a number of 8 pixels by padding.

I wrote Node.JS script. Before run script install module jimp (`npm install jimp`). Tested on Node.JS v9.2.0 and jimp 0.2.28.

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const util = require('util')

const Jimp = require('jimp')

const main = async () => {
    if (process.argv.length != 4) {
        console.log('Need two args: input filename and result filename')
        console.log(`Example: ${process.argv[0]} ${process.argv[1]} HomeBackground.cpbitmap HomeBackground.png`)
        return
    }

    const inpFileName = process.argv[2]
    const outFileName = process.argv[3]

    const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile)

    const cpbmp = await readFile(inpFileName)
    const width = cpbmp.readInt32LE(cpbmp.length - 4 * 5)
    const height = cpbmp.readInt32LE(cpbmp.length - 4 * 4)

    console.log(`Image height: ${height}, width: ${width}`)

    const image = await new Jimp(width, height, 0x000000FF)

    const calcOffsetInCpbmp = (x, y, width) => {
        const lineSize = Math.ceil(width / 8) * 8
        return x * 4 + y * lineSize * 4
    }

    const calcOffsetInImage = (x, y, width) => {
        return x * 4 + y * width * 4
    }

    const swapRBColors = (c) => {
        const r = c & 0xFF
        const b = (c & 0xFF0000) >> 16
        c &= 0xFF00FF00
        c |= r << 16
        c |= b
        return c
    }

    for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            const color = cpbmp.readInt32LE(calcOffsetInCpbmp(x, y, width))
            image.bitmap.data.writeInt32LE(swapRBColors(color), calcOffsetInImage(x, y, width))
        }
    }

    await image.write(outFileName)

    console.log('Done')
}

main()
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: I just tried this and the images don't come out correctly. There must be something I'm not understanding. The images come out looking like this: https://imgur.com/Oj4TQDV. Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, it turns out the offset has been increased to 16, so I just changed the 8's in the lineSize constant to 16's and everything works great!

Comment: Thank you @dr15, I published a GitHub repository and credited your answer as the source. 
- 
https://github.com/hthetiot/cpbitmap-to-png/blob/main/README.md

My father had an old iphone 5 on iOS 10 and wanted to get the lock screen and home screen picture but it was not in his photo so i was able to dump it from the backup and convert it using your solution. Thank you!